# SQL query taking input from a file

Tags: python, mysql

I have following SQL query -

```
SELECT * FROM users where id=X
```

Here 'X' is the set of values which need to be read from a file say `~/ids.lst`. I have following approach in hand.

1. Read ids.lst and load all variables.
2. For each variable form and fire an SQL query and concat the results.

I have working code in **python**, but the problem is if I have *n* ids, then *n* queries will be made to server. Is there any way I could achieve the same with a single query to server?

Comment: Show us the code then we can help you

Comment: I can't! My query is not exactly what I mentioned above. It is a code which I can't make public, but with the algo above, the motive should be well understood!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `in` operator for single query.

```
SELECT * FROM users where id in (<concat ids with , (comma) read from file.>)
```

This will be single query and faster compare to individual query.

Comment: Aweseome! It is exactly what I was looking for.